# Can`t access my Patriot SSD disk

Tags: linux, ssd

I have problems with my ssd disk. This disk is used less than 6m.
I install on it Windows 10 and after this Debian linux and use linux. Windows is used very rare.

I have updates on my linux and restart system. And problems start. It give me a lot of input/output errors (i don`t have pic of them).
Now i have connected disk on other computer again with Win10 and linux.

This is situation on ssd disk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 223,57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: Patriot Burst El
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x393a909f

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         1126400 183175167 182048768  86,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       183175168 184262655   1087488   531M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb4       184262656 468862127 284599472 135,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       184264704 188166143   3901440   1,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       188168192 468860927 280692736 133,8G 83 Linux
```

Sometimes it show me /home folder and my name but folders inside are empty.

Yesterday it show me that there is no partitions on disk.
From yesterday work testdis with deepscan, but no luck.
Today after restart with fdisk -l i see partition above.
Now i try to scan for badblocks but i receive this

```
sudo e2fsck -cfpv /dev/sdb1
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

/dev/sdb1 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'System Reserved'

So i skip to sda6 where is my /home folder and important data:

```
star@stars:~$ sudo e2fsck -cfpv /dev/sdb6
/dev/sdb6: recovering journal
Error reading block 27262992 (Input/output error) while reading inode and block bitmaps.  

/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Error reading block 2097152 (Input/output error) while reading inode and block bitmaps.  

/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Error reading block 10485761 (Input/output error) while reading inode and block bitmaps.  

/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Signal (11) SIGSEGV si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x60
e2fsck(+0x31ece)[0x558e5ee78ece]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f4854642520]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(ext2fs_super_and_bgd_loc2+0x43)[0x7f4854a12cf3]
Error reading block 18874368 (Input/output error) while reading inode and block bitmaps.  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(ext2fs_flush2+0x226)[0x7f4854a159d6]


/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(ext2fs_close2+0x11b)[0x7f4854a1db0b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(ext2fs_close_free+0x1a)[0x7f4854a1db9a]
Signal (11) SIGSEGV e2fsck(preenhalt+0x8d)[0x558e5ee6f84d]
si_code=SEGV_MAPERR fault addr=0x3a
e2fsck(+0x36fa9)[0x558e5ee7dfa9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(+0x40d0f)[0x7f4854a42d0f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(+0x3ca17)[0x7f4854a3ea17]
e2fsck(+0x31ece)[0x558e5ee78ece]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f4854642520]
e2fsck(preenhalt+0x7f)[0x558e5ee6f83f]
e2fsck(+0x36fa9)[0x558e5ee7dfa9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(+0x40d0f)[0x7f4854a42d0f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(+0x3ca17)[0x7f4854a3ea17]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2(+0x3cce1)[0x7f4854a3ece1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94b43)[0x7f4854694b43]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a00)[0x7f4854726a00]
star@stars:~$
```

What other to try?

Comment: Can we see SMART?

Comment: Is it the same problem on Windows ?

Comment: Get the SSD manufacturer’s drive test App on USB and test the drive